# How to disable LinkedIn birthday event notification in mac calendar?

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, notifications, ical

I have a lot of connections in LinkedIn and due to this every time when I open my laptop I got notification about there birthday.

My calendar looks like this

[image]

It is very inconvenient, how knows how to disable these events or discard linkedIn from calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found was to disable LinkedIn in your Contacts "Preferences > Accounts".  That is how I could prevent them from showing in my Calendar.

I highly recommend you to send [feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ical.html) about this.